# Visual Studio help on LAN server

Tags: visual-studio, lan

so you can choose between online help and installing help files locally in Visual Studio, right? I was wondering if it's possible to do something in between: installing help contents on a server in the LAN and pointing VS to that source.

Thing is: I like to have my help pop up instantly without any lag but I don't want to waste space on my workstations SSD for that. After all I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 server running which has tons of disk space and should perform as fast as the local web server of VS.

Is there a way to accomplish that? I've got MSDNAA access, so even if I'd need additional software it's likely I can get it there.

Thanks.

Edit: To clarify what I want to accomplish: If you use local help, your browser will open a certain website from 127.0.0.1 thats hosted by a component of the help-viewer that comes with some sort of mini http service. That thing renders the request URL into a lookup in the right help database. I want that help database on my server and iis to process the requests similar to this help thingy. Plus on the client side I want to tell the help viewer not to use `127.0.0.1:47873/help` as base but rather something like `garfield/devel/docs/vs2010`.

Answer (score 2):

In C:\Program Files\Microsoft Help Viewer\v1.0, you've got an help file ReadMe_ENG.htm.

It said that :

> If port 47873 is used by another process (not via the http.sys service) then the Help Library Agent will not be able to attach and use port 47873 and will fail. The port number can be changed by adding a string registry value AgentPort under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Help\v1.0 with the value of the port to use (eg. 81).

In regedit, I've got :

- LocalStore = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\HelpLibrary\
- AppRoot = C:\Program Files\Microsoft Help Viewer\v1.0\

The LocalStore directory, in my HDD, contain 2.3Go of data (*.mshi, *.mshc...)

So, I believe that if you move this content to a shared directory....it **MAY** work

I cannot test, so it's only suppositions...

Comment: that's a good place to start, thank you... maybe there's a way to configure the web address vs is looking at for the help, too... but still there's the problem of getting the help contents onto the server cleanly and update them there as well

Comment: You also can look in this dir : C:\Program Files\Microsoft Help Viewer\v1.0
When I show help (ctrl+F1 , V), it launch HelpLibAgent.exe (with parameters).
And with the help's management (ctrl+F1, M), it launch HelpLibManager.exe (also with parameters)

Comment: I looked into this yesterday.... Seems like you can copy the program dir onto the server and start the helplibmanager with the right parameters to download and update help. BUT: I can't figure HelpLibAgent out. It Loads some kind of web server from that other dll file in the program folder, that somehow maps the requested url to a query to the help database and put out the results... I don't know how to run this under IIS nor do I know how to configure the client to use this help accordingly (online and local help show different url structures)

Comment: Same conclusion here, HelpLibAgent load a specific webserver. The port can be modify in registry, but I did not find where we can change the url... The only parameters that can be change is from localhost or online help (maybe an if in the code XD)